# Compare and merge data from 2 tables with same structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Having 2 tables with the same structure, like this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa7f0/2), is it possible to build a SQL statement that compares the values of the columns of both tables (where id is the unique key), and return a list of the change columns in the format:

```
columnname, oldvalue, newvalue
```

Where `oldvalue` is the value in `Table1` and `newvalue` is the value in `Table2`.

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Id
      ,'Name' AS ColumnName
      ,CAST(T1.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OldValue
      ,CAST(T2.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
FROM Table1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.id = T2.id
UNION
SELECT T1.Id
      ,'Amount'
      ,CAST(T1.amount AS VARCHAR(MAX))
      ,CAST(T2.amount AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM Table1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MERGE statement , please note it is only available from SQL 2008 onwards

here is an example

```
MERGE Production.ProductInventory AS target
USING (SELECT ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
    ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    AND soh.OrderDate = @OrderDate
    GROUP BY ProductID) AS source (ProductID, OrderQty)
ON (target.ProductID = source.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED AND target.Quantity - source.OrderQty <= 0
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET target.Quantity = target.Quantity - source.OrderQty, 
                    target.ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.ProductID, Inserted.Quantity, Inserted.ModifiedDate, Deleted.ProductID,
    Deleted.Quantity, Deleted.ModifiedDate;
GO
```

you can learn more about merge's here [SQL merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: What is this? This doesn't produce the desired output and this doesn't even use the table schema provided.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want rows with differences:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.Id, T2.Id) Id
      ,'Name' AS ColumnName
      ,CAST(T1.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OldValue
      ,CAST(T2.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
FROM Table1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE COALESCE(T1.name,'**') != COALESCE(T2.name ,'**')
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(T1.Id, T2.Id) Id
      ,'Amount' AS ColumnName
      ,CAST(T1.Amount AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OldValue
      ,CAST(T2.Amount AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
FROM Table1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE COALESCE(T1.Amount,0) != COALESCE(T2.Amount,0)
```